# Installing PyGame - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, pygame

My current version of `Python` is the newest 3.5 and the only available `PyGame` was for 3.2 (both PyGame and Python are 32-bit). I've scoured stackoverflow for a resolution and can't find any way to make this work. I've installed the `PyGame` easy installer and placed it in the directory where my Python install is, and in `Visual Studio` (I've also tried this in `PyCharm` as well as the standard Python IDE in command prompt), upon typing 
import pygame or import sys, pygame
I'm presented with the error Import Error was

```
unhandled by user code - DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

My final solution is to uninstall Python 3.5 and install the version which matches PyGame.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't have anything to do with Python version. You are missing a dynamic library (the DLL). This means that either the DLL is not on your system or Python can't find it. You should probably try the msi/exe installer for PyGame [mentioned here](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted), as it should install any dependencies. This would fix the issue if it is caused by the DLL being absent from your system.

It could also be caused by the libraries not being on `PYTHONPATH`. Search the error you received and you should see quite a few answers on fixing this.

If you're just getting started, you may want to look at a different library. There are likely quite a few game libraries for Python that can be installed with a simple `pip install`. You could then return to PyGame when you are more comfortable if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

get it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnmcaq1rf6zn7m3/pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl?dl=0
download it and install it by putting it in C:\python3.5\Scripts
then run pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
(this is for 3.4, but 3.5 works too)
it should work, and your error has nothing to do with the package, it's just that you do not have a DLL file, install it again from the website above

Comment: Following the steps you gave me I enter python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl and the cmd returns this error. http://imgur.com/a/W6Gxz